# What's the word for a small present to appease someone's anger?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's the word for a small present to appease someone's anger?

I picked it up a couple of months ago from The Economist but can't remember it now. As far as I can recall it wasn't a multi-syllabic word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**sop**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sop) (ODOL)
noun (plural **sops**)

> 1 A thing of no great value given or done as a concession to appease someone whose main concerns or demands are not being met.
>   *‘my agent telephones as a sop but never finds me work’*

Answer (score 1):

If you want something neutral, try **peace offering**:

> a gift or service for the purpose of procuring peace or reconciliation
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peace%20offering)</sub>

If you want pejorative, try **bribe**:

> money or a gift that you give to someone so that they will do something for you, often something dishonest
>   <sub>[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bribe)</sub>

Comment: *Peace offering* may not be what Op is after, but it is more practical. I've heard it a lot precisely in op's case.